# Where is "Today" and "Yesterday" in Finder menu?

Tags: finder, macos

A folder or place search place that contained everything I used "Today" and "Yesterday" is missing from my new Yosemite finder on the left.  Is it not possible to have this?  It was a quick easy way to recall specific things when working on a lot of different things.

Answer (score 1):

They don't appear to be there by default, but you can add them back in pretty easily.

[image: Screenshot of Finder offering to save search and add to sidebar]

1. Open a Finder window
2. Type "today" into the search box.
3. It should offer you two options in a dropdown menu "Dates: today" and "Filenames - Name Matches: today". Pick the dates option.
4. The search should complete and the search bar should appear saying "This Mac" and the name of which ever folder the Finder window had opened. Choose "This Mac".
5. The search bar should also offer you a "Save" button. Click Save.
6. A Save panel should appear allowing you to specify a name and location for the saved search. There should also be a "Add To Sidebar" check box. Check the box.

Repeat for "Yesterday".